# Reference tag from comment

Tags: github

Is it possible to reference a tag in an Issue Comment? Like you can reference issues and commits, I want to reference a tag.

> The Writer implementation is available since tag v0.0.1.

Comment: All github markdown is at https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by [referring to the commit SHA](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#references) that added that tag.

Look up the tag via the Branches/Tags dropdown list or in the Releases (since on [GitHub releases are tied to tags](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software)).

When you load up the tag, you can grab the commit SHA from the top of the file list, where it says,

> latest commit XXX {clipboard-icon}

And then reference it as you normally would any other SHA.

Comment: Tags can be changed to point to another commit, so there is a scenario where you might run into issues with this approach. Another alternative would be to link to the releases, which has a url for each tag. Note: Changing tags on a repo is *not* a good practice, so using the commit is a reasonable approach. It only becomes an issue if there's a need to rewrite tag history in the repo.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, GitHub. Thanks for sharing, at least I know it's not possible.